# Valgrind memcheck tool report miss match delete for c++, but delete operation is in another class/struct

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a struct in data_buf.h:

```
struct DataBuffer {
  uint8_t* buffer;
  size_t buf_size;
  size_t data_start;
  size_t data_len;
  int dst_offset;

  DataBuffer(uint8_t* buf, size_t sz, size_t ds, size_t dl, int doff);
  ~DataBuffer();
};
```

data_buf.cpp

```
DataBuffer::DataBuffer(uint8_t* buf, size_t sz,
                   size_t ds, size_t dl,
                   int doff)
  :buffer{buf},
   buf_size{sz},
   data_start{ds},
   data_len{dl},
   dst_offset{doff} {}

DataBuffer::~DataBuffer() {
  if (buffer) {
  delete [] buffer;
  }
}
```

So in the class data_proc_hdl.h:
    #include "data_buf.h"

```
class DataProcessHandler {
 public:
  DataProcessHandler(int buf_len);

 private:
  DataBuffer m_data;
}
```

The constructor looks like:

```
DataProcessHandler::DataProcessHandler(int buf_len)
  :m_data{new uint8_t[buf_len], buf_len, 0, 0, -1} {}
```

No self define destructor for Class Usage.

And ClientHandler is derived from DataProcessHandler,

So:

```
ClientHandler* u = new ClientHandler(10);
u->do_something();
delete u;
```

I think it is OK, the data buffer allocated will be freed in DataBuffer's 
destructor, but the Valgrind out put:

```
==12419== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==12419==    at 0x49421D4: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:621)
==12419==    by 0x10EABB: ~DataProcessHandler (data_proc_hdl.h:19)
==12419==    by 0x10EABB: ClientHandler::~ClientHandler()     (client_hdl.cpp:81)
==12419==    by 0x10EAE3: ClientHandler::~ClientHandler() (client_hdl.cpp:62)
==12419==    by 0x112EF3: ClientManager::process_client_disconn(ClientHandler*) (client_mgr.cpp:85)
==12419==    by 0x126153: Multiplexer::run() (multiplexer.cpp:182)
==12419==    by 0x11515F: main (cp_log.cpp:93)
==12419==  Address 0x4be50b0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 256 alloc'd
==12419==    at 0x4940660: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==12419==    by 0x49FC5EB: operator new(unsigned long) (in /system/lib64/libc++.so)
==12419==    by 0x116E9B: DataProcessHandler::DataProcessHandler(int, LogController*, Multiplexer*, unsigned long) (data_proc_hdl.cpp:18)
==12419==    by 0x10E853: ClientHandler::ClientHandler(int, LogController*, Multiplexer*, ClientManager*) (client_hdl.cpp:50)
==12419==    by 0x112E07: ClientManager::process(int) (client_mgr.cpp:71)
==12419==    by 0x126153: Multiplexer::run() (multiplexer.cpp:182)
==12419==    by 0x11515F: main (cp_log.cpp:93)
```

Qestion:
  Is it true, there is a memory leak or just because it is not a good design for manage data buffer like this?

Comment: use unique_ptr for buffer and don't worry about it anymore - if you need to send in the memory from outside. If not, do what the comment below says.

Comment: For `DataBuffer::buffer`, why don't you make it a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Then you don't have to worry about manual memory allocation or deallocation.

Comment: More related to your problem, please edit your question to include more of the Valgrind output, preferably all of it, with a matching [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also build your program with debug information (add the `-g` flag when compiling) and Valgrind should be able to tell you file-names and line-numbers.

Comment: Also related to your problem: Do you pass around the `DataBuffer` object by value? Do you make copies of it? Then do you follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: Yes, more context for the Valgrind error would help so that we can see the allocation and deallocation stacks

Comment: is valgrind result always right?

Answer (score 0):

Mismatched free() / delete / delete [] means that you are mixing up your allocation and deallocation functions.

For instance you could be

- allocating with `malloc` and deallocating with `delete` or `delete[]`
- allocating with `new` and deallocating with `free` or `delete[]`
- allocating with `new[]` and deallocating with `free` or `delete`

(note that there are several more allocation functions such as calloc and posix_memalign)

This can lead to a leak e.g., if you allocate with `new` and deallocate with `free` the destructor will not get called resulting in an indirect leak.

This can also potentially cause memory corruption and crashes. For instance, if you replace malloc and new with versions that use different memory pools. In this case if you use a function to free memory from the wrong pool you are likely to corrupt that pool.

Finally, this could be a false alert. In particular if you have any replacement functions that may be inlined in optimized code then Valgrind will not see the inlined function in the callstack. If you compile without optimization or a 'no inline' flag you should be able to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Thanks for clarification